# jQuery not working after ajax call Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, blogger

I've added infinite scrolling to my blogger template but I run into a problem where jQuery doesn't work on posts loaded with infinite scrolling as shown in the picture below:

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy8KR.png)

this just an example of time ago plugin, the first 2 posts loaded with the page normally and others loaded with infinite scrolling

I'm using this timeago script:

```js
// Timeago jQuery plugin ~ URL: http://timeago.yarp.com
(function(e){if(typeof define==="function"&&define.amd){define(["jquery"],e)}else{e(jQuery)}})(function(e){function r(){var n=i(this);var r=t.settings;if(!isNaN(n.datetime)){if(r.cutoff==0||Math.abs(o(n.datetime))<r.cutoff){e(this).text(s(n.datetime))}}return this}function i(n){n=e(n);if(!n.data("timeago")){n.data("timeago",{datetime:t.datetime(n)});var r=e.trim(n.text());if(t.settings.localeTitle){n.attr("title",n.data("timeago").datetime.toLocaleString())}else if(r.length>0&&!(t.isTime(n)&&n.attr("title"))){n.attr("title",r)}}return n.data("timeago")}function s(e){return t.inWords(o(e))}function o(e){return(new Date).getTime()-e.getTime()}e.timeago=function(t){if(t instanceof Date){return s(t)}else if(typeof t==="string"){return s(e.timeago.parse(t))}else if(typeof t==="number"){return s(new Date(t))}else{return s(e.timeago.datetime(t))}};var t=e.timeago;e.extend(e.timeago,{settings:{refreshMillis:6e4,allowPast:true,allowFuture:false,localeTitle:false,cutoff:0,strings:{prefixAgo:null,prefixFromNow:null,suffixAgo:"ago",suffixFromNow:"from now",inPast:"in a moment",seconds:"a few seconds",minute:"%d minute",minutes:"%d mins",hour:"%d hour",hours:"%d hrs",day:"%d day",days:"%d days",month:"%d month",months:"%d months",year:"%d year",years:"%d years",wordSeparator:" ",numbers:[]}},inWords:function(t){function l(r,i){var s=e.isFunction(r)?r(i,t):r;var o=n.numbers&&n.numbers[i]||i;return s.replace(/%d/i,o)}if(!this.settings.allowPast&&!this.settings.allowFuture){throw"timeago allowPast and allowFuture settings can not both be set to false."}var n=this.settings.strings;var r=n.prefixAgo;var i=n.suffixAgo;if(this.settings.allowFuture){if(t<0){r=n.prefixFromNow;i=n.suffixFromNow}}if(!this.settings.allowPast&&t>=0){return this.settings.strings.inPast}var s=Math.abs(t)/1e3;var o=s/60;var u=o/60;var a=u/24;var f=a/365;var c=s<45&&l(n.seconds,Math.round(s))||s<90&&l(n.minute,1)||o<45&&l(n.minutes,Math.round(o))||o<90&&l(n.hour,1)||u<24&&l(n.hours,Math.round(u))||u<42&&l(n.day,1)||a<30&&l(n.days,Math.round(a))||a<45&&l(n.month,1)||a<365&&l(n.months,Math.round(a/30))||f<1.5&&l(n.year,1)||l(n.years,Math.round(f));var h=n.wordSeparator||"";if(n.wordSeparator===undefined){h=" "}return e.trim([r,c,i].join(h))},parse:function(t){var n=e.trim(t);n=n.replace(/\.\d+/,"");n=n.replace(/-/,"/").replace(/-/,"/");n=n.replace(/T/," ").replace(/Z/," UTC");n=n.replace(/([\+\-]\d\d)\:?(\d\d)/," $1$2");n=n.replace(/([\+\-]\d\d)$/," $100");return new Date(n)},datetime:function(n){var r=t.isTime(n)?e(n).attr("datetime"):e(n).attr("title");return t.parse(r)},isTime:function(t){return e(t).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase()==="time"}});var n={init:function(){var n=e.proxy(r,this);n();var i=t.settings;if(i.refreshMillis>0){this._timeagoInterval=setInterval(n,i.refreshMillis)}},update:function(n){var i=t.parse(n);e(this).data("timeago",{datetime:i});if(t.settings.localeTitle)e(this).attr("title",i.toLocaleString());r.apply(this)},updateFromDOM:function(){e(this).data("timeago",{datetime:t.parse(t.isTime(this)?e(this).attr("datetime"):e(this).attr("title"))});r.apply(this)},dispose:function(){if(this._timeagoInterval){window.clearInterval(this._timeagoInterval);this._timeagoInterval=null}}};e.fn.timeago=function(e,t){var r=e?n[e]:n.init;if(!r){throw new Error("Unknown function name '"+e+"' for timeago")}this.each(function(){r.call(this,t)});return this};document.createElement("abbr");document.createElement("time")});
```

and this one is the infinite scrolling plugin

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
(function($){'use strict';Date.now=Date.now||function(){return+new Date()};$.ias=function(g){var h=$.extend({},$.ias.defaults,g);var i=new $.ias.util();var j=new $.ias.paging(h.scrollContainer);var k=(h.history?new $.ias.history():false);var l=this;function init(){var d;j.onChangePage(function(a,b,c){if(k){k.setPage(a,c)}h.onPageChange.call(this,a,c,b)});reset();if(k&&k.havePage()){stop_scroll();d=k.getPage();i.forceScrollTop(function(){var a;if(d>1){paginateToPage(d);a=get_scroll_threshold(true);$('html, body').scrollTop(a)}else{reset()}})}return l}init();function reset(){hide_pagination();h.scrollContainer.scroll(scroll_handler)}function scroll_handler(){var a,scrThreshold;a=i.getCurrentScrollOffset(h.scrollContainer);scrThreshold=get_scroll_threshold();if(a>=scrThreshold){if(get_current_page()>=h.triggerPageThreshold){stop_scroll();show_trigger(function(){paginate(a)})}else{paginate(a)}}}function stop_scroll(){h.scrollContainer.unbind('scroll',scroll_handler)}function hide_pagination(){$(h.pagination).hide()}function get_scroll_threshold(a){var b,threshold;b=$(h.container).find(h.item).last();if(b.size()===0){return 0}threshold=b.offset().top+b.height();if(!a){threshold+=h.thresholdMargin}return threshold}function paginate(d,e){var f;f=$(h.next).attr('href');if(!f){if(h.noneleft){$(h.container).find(h.item).last().after(h.noneleft)}return stop_scroll()}if(h.beforePageChange&&$.isFunction(h.beforePageChange)){if(h.beforePageChange(d,f)===false){return}}j.pushPages(d,f);stop_scroll();show_loader();loadItems(f,function(a,b){var c=h.onLoadItems.call(this,b),curLastItem;if(c!==false){$(b).hide();curLastItem=$(h.container).find(h.item).last();curLastItem.after(b);$(b).fadeIn()}f=$(h.next,a).attr('href');$(h.pagination).replaceWith($(h.pagination,a));remove_loader();hide_pagination();if(f){reset()}else{stop_scroll()}h.onRenderComplete.call(this,b);if(e){e.call(this)}})}function loadItems(b,c,d){var e=[],container,startTime=Date.now(),diffTime,self;d=d||h.loaderDelay;$.get(b,null,function(a){container=$(h.container,a).eq(0);if(0===container.length){container=$(a).filter(h.container).eq(0)}if(container){container.find(h.item).each(function(){e.push(this)})}if(c){self=this;diffTime=Date.now()-startTime;if(diffTime<d){setTimeout(function(){c.call(self,a,e)},d-diffTime)}else{c.call(self,a,e)}}},'html')}function paginateToPage(a){var b=get_scroll_threshold(true);if(b>0){paginate(b,function(){stop_scroll();if((j.getCurPageNum(b)+1)<a){paginateToPage(a);$('html,body').animate({'scrollTop':b},400,'swing')}else{$('html,body').animate({'scrollTop':b},1000,'swing');reset()}})}}function get_current_page(){var a=i.getCurrentScrollOffset(h.scrollContainer);return j.getCurPageNum(a)}function get_loader(){var a=$('.ias_loader');if(a.size()===0){a=$('<div class="ias_loader">'+h.loader+'</div>');a.hide()}return a}function show_loader(){var a=get_loader(),el;if(h.customLoaderProc!==false){h.customLoaderProc(a)}else{el=$(h.container).find(h.item).last();el.after(a);a.fadeIn()}}function remove_loader(){var a=get_loader();a.remove()}function get_trigger(a){var b=$('.ias_trigger');if(b.size()===0){b=$('<div class="ias_trigger"><a href="#">'+h.trigger+'</a></div>');b.hide()}$('a',b).off('click').on('click',function(){remove_trigger();a.call();return false});return b}function show_trigger(a){var b=get_trigger(a),el;el=$(h.container).find(h.item).last();el.after(b);b.fadeIn()}function remove_trigger(){var a=get_trigger();a.remove()}};$.ias.defaults={container:'.blog-posts',scrollContainer:$(window),item:'.post-outer',pagination:'#blog-pager',next:'#blog-pager-older-link a',loader:'<div clear:both;><img  style="clear:both;display: block;margin: auto;" src="https://loading.io/spinners/coolors/index.palette-rotating-ring-loader.gif"/></div>',loaderDelay:600,triggerPageThreshold:1000,trigger:'Load more Posts',thresholdMargin:-500,history:true,onPageChange:function(){},beforePageChange:function(){},onLoadItems:function(){},onRenderComplete:function(){ FB.XFBML.parse(); gapi.plusone.go(); twttr.widgets.load(); _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); },customLoaderProc:false};$.ias.util=function(){var c=false;var d=false;var e=this;function init(){$(window).load(function(){c=true})}init();this.forceScrollTop=function(a){$('html,body').scrollTop(0);if(!d){if(!c){setTimeout(function(){e.forceScrollTop(a)},1)}else{a.call();d=true}}};this.getCurrentScrollOffset=function(a){var b,wndHeight;if(a.get(0)===window){b=a.scrollTop()}else{b=a.offset().top}wndHeight=a.height();return b+wndHeight}};$.ias.paging=function(){var c=[[0,document.location.toString()]];var d=function(){};var e=1;var f=new $.ias.util();function init(){$(window).scroll(scroll_handler)}init();function scroll_handler(){var a,curPageNum,curPagebreak,scrOffset,urlPage;a=f.getCurrentScrollOffset($(window));curPageNum=getCurPageNum(a);curPagebreak=getCurPagebreak(a);if(e!==curPageNum){scrOffset=curPagebreak[0];urlPage=curPagebreak[1];d.call({},curPageNum,scrOffset,urlPage)}e=curPageNum}function getCurPageNum(a){for(var i=(c.length-1);i>0;i--){if(a>c[i][0]){return i+1}}return 1}this.getCurPageNum=function(a){a=a||f.getCurrentScrollOffset($(window));return getCurPageNum(a)};function getCurPagebreak(a){for(var i=(c.length-1);i>=0;i--){if(a>c[i][0]){return c[i]}}return null}this.onChangePage=function(a){d=a};this.pushPages=function(a,b){c.push([a,b])}};$.ias.history=function(){var e=false;var f=false;function init(){f=!!(window.history&&history.pushState&&history.replaceState);f=false}init();this.setPage=function(a,b){this.updateState({page:a},'',b)};this.havePage=function(){return(this.getState()!==false)};this.getPage=function(){var a;if(this.havePage()){a=this.getState();return a.page}return 1};this.getState=function(){var a,stateObj,pageNum;if(f){stateObj=history.state;if(stateObj&&stateObj.ias){return stateObj.ias}}else{a=(window.location.hash.substring(0,7)==='#/page/');if(a){pageNum=parseInt(window.location.hash.replace('#/page/',''),10);return{page:pageNum}}}return false};this.updateState=function(a,b,c){if(e){this.replaceState(a,b,c)}else{this.pushState(a,b,c)}};this.pushState=function(a,b,c){var d;if(f){history.pushState({ias:a},b,c)}else{d=(a.page>0?'#/page/'+a.page:'');window.location.hash=d}e=true};this.replaceState=function(a,b,c){if(f){history.replaceState({ias:a},b,c)}else{this.pushState(a,b,c)}}}})(jQuery);
//]]>
</script>
<script>jQuery.ias();</script>
```

I hope you help, I'm tired trying to fix it. thank you.

Comment: When you load the new content try also calling `jQuery("timeago").timeago();`.  If your loader supports a `done()` handler it would probably go there.

Comment: thanks but its not working, its not only timeago not working but everything that works with jquery, timeago is just an example